# Потоки и элементы формы

Tags: c++-cli

Вот пример синхронных потоков. Вопрос, как мне в них использовать значение тексбокса,
то есть как мне записать значение textbox в переменную и обратно из переменной в textbox

```
String^ q1;
q1= textBox1->Text;
textBox2->Text = q1;
```

Вот все это выполнить только в потоках. Желательно с примером, так сам не смог разобраться. Заранее спс. =)

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Threading;
const int numThreads = 10;
const int numThreadIterations = 5;
ref class MyInterlockedExchangeExampleClass
{
public:
   static void MyThreadProc()
   {
      for ( int i = 0; i < numThreadIterations; i++ )
      {
         UseResource();

         //Wait 1 second before next attempt.
         Thread::Sleep( 1000 );

      }
   }

private:

   //A simple method that denies reentrancy.
   static bool UseResource()
   {

      //0 indicates that the method is not in use.
      if ( 0 == Interlocked::Exchange( usingResource, 1 ) )
      {

         //Code to access a resource that is not thread safe would go here.
         //Simulate some work
         Thread::Sleep( 500 );

         //Release the lock
         Interlocked::Exchange( usingResource, 0 );
         return true;
      }
      else
      {

         return false;
      }
   }

   //0 for false, 1 for true.
   static int usingResource;
   static Object^ globalMso = gcnew Object;
};
```

***c++ cli***

Answer (score 1):

Если текстовое поле напрямую доступно из двух и более потоков на чтение-запись, то чтобы избежать взаимовлияния, потоков используют различные виды синхронизации. В примере из MSDN, который вы привели, используется значение переменной usingResource, которая изменяется и сравнивается с помощью атомарных операций. В итоге код, который обернут вызовами Interlocked

```
if ( 0 == Interlocked::Exchange( usingResource, 1 ) )
{
    // ...
    // Здесь осуществляется доступ к защищенному ресурсу

    Interlocked::Exchange( usingResource, 0 );
```

защищен от многократного входжения, то есть невозможна ситуация, когда, например, один поток начинает читать значение переменной, а в середине чтения вклинивается поток и пишет в переменную. Логика проста, как только один поток входит в секцию за Interlocked, значение usingResource приравнивается к единице, и все последующие потоки уже не входят в секцию за Interlocked до тех пор, пока первый поток не выйдет из нее.

Comment: вы вопрос читали? я как это все и так знаю покажите код как реализовать чтение запись в тексбокс в этих потоках О_о а ту я уже себе скоро все волосы повыдергиваю =(